# Where did the phrase "hairy eyeball" come from?

Tags: etymology

Used by some in my place of work as a colloquialism for a disapproving or skeptical attitude toward something.

Jane was giving Jack the "hairy eyeball".

Comment: There is some informed speculation here: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-hai5.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/83338?redirectedFrom=hairy%20eyeball#eid2200587) reveals:

> hairy eyeball  n. slang (orig. and chiefly U.S.) a look given with
>   narrowed eyes; esp. one indicating hostility or disapproval;
>   frequently in to give the hairy eyeball.

As in:

> 1961   Reno (Nevada) Evening Gaz. 11 Nov. 2/2   ‘He gave me the hairy
>   eyeball.’ That meant he liked her.

Answer (score -1):

The hairy eyeball is a look of disapproval or skepticism.  I believe the term comes from the fact your eyes (or in some cases just one of them) is squinted, thus partially covering your eyeball with your eyelashes - HAIR!